# Does Google Cloud Composer support connecting to AWS resource like S3 and Redshift?

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I am planning to use Google Cloud Composer to schedule a workflow which is loading data from S3 to Redshift. As S3 and Redshift are all based on AWS, I want to know whether Google Cloud Composer allows me to do it.

From my understanding after reading the document, I am able to install AWS SDK from PYPI and install local Python dependencies, which means that I can build my own library for S3Connection and RedshiftConnection to make the workflow work. Anyone with experience on it can help confirm it? Thanks

Comment: Is the answer enough to answer your question? Just want to make sure..

Comment: I am considering a similar setup. To me, the biggest question is how to connect and authenticate between the two different clouds. Has anybody done this and if so how?

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Composer is built to support hybrid and multi-cloud as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/).

Cloud Composer can make use of existing [Airflow operators](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/airflow/operators) which includes a [S3toRedshift operator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/s3_to_redshift_operator.py) that uses the [S3 hook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.py) and the [postgres hook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/postgres_hook.py) for Redshift

Cloud Composer can also use custom plugins. The way to install custom plugins in Cloud Composer is described in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/plugins).